# execute javascript on every reload - ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am reloading partial using ajax this way:

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('content', '/shouts/update.js', { method: 'get', frequency: 1});
```

The reload is working great.

I added this javascript code to update.js to make the partial content fade:

```
$('content').fade({ duration: 3.0, from: 0, to: 1 });
```

And the problem is that nothing happens (the content doesn't fade).

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: What is the content of '/shouts/update.js' ?

Comment: $('content').fade({ duration: 3.0, from: 0, to: 1 }); is the only content. The problem is that the javascript is not being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I think the problem is that there is no fade function in JQuery... Try fadeTo</strike>

```
$('content').fadeTo(3000, 0);
```

also there is the function fadeToggle(). There you have a simple switch :)

UPDATE: thought it is was jquery... within Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater you can set the parameter `evalScripts` to `true` then the script will be available... 
http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/